# MONAI (pytorch) def train zero division error

Tags: python, pytorch, medical, medical-imaging

I've been following a liver segmentation Monai based code set off of https://github.com/amine0110/Liver-Segmentation-Using-Monai-and-PyTorch. However when I run def train, I'm getting the error:

```
----------
epoch 1/100
--------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-22328907c897> in <cell line: 16>()
     36 
     37     if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 38         train(model, data_in, loss_function, optimizer, 100, model_dir)

<ipython-input-26-6b8beda06825> in train(model, data_in, loss, optim, max_epochs, model_dir, test_interval, device)
     77         print('-'*20)
     78 
---> 79         train_epoch_loss /= train_step
     80         print(f'Epoch_loss: {train_epoch_loss:.4f}')
     81         save_loss_train.append(train_epoch_loss)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Changing the number close to 0 although not 0 however distorts the model significantly (i.e. 0.01). Is there any way we can alter the codes such that it works but it doesn't change test dice loss and test dice metric plot signficantly?

````
    best_metric = -1
    best_metric_epoch = -1
    save_loss_train = []
    save_loss_test = []
    save_metric_train = []
    save_metric_test = []
    train_loader, test_loader = data_in

    for epoch in range(max_epochs):
        print("-" * 10)
        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1}/{max_epochs}")
        model.train()
        train_epoch_loss = 0
        train_step = 0
        epoch_metric_train = 0
        for batch_data in train_loader:
            
            train_step += 1

            volume = batch_data["vol"]
            label = batch_data["seg"]
            label = label != 0
            volume, label = (volume.to(device), label.to(device))

            optim.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(volume)
            
            train_loss = loss(outputs, label)
            
            train_loss.backward()
            optim.step()

            train_epoch_loss += train_loss.item()
            print(
                f"{train_step}/{len(train_loader) // train_loader.batch_size}, "
                f"Train_loss: {train_loss.item():.4f}")

            train_metric = dice_metric(outputs, label)
            epoch_metric_train += train_metric
            print(f'Train_dice: {train_metric:.4f}')

        print('-'*20)
        
        train_epoch_loss /= train_step
        print(f'Epoch_loss: {train_epoch_loss:.4f}')
        save_loss_train.append(train_epoch_loss)
        np.save(os.path.join(model_dir, 'loss_train.npy'), save_loss_train)
        
        epoch_metric_train /= train_step
        print(f'Epoch_metric: {epoch_metric_train:.4f}')

        save_metric_train.append(epoch_metric_train)
        np.save(os.path.join(model_dir, 'metric_train.npy'), save_metric_train)

        if (epoch + 1) % test_interval == 0:

            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                test_epoch_loss = 0
                test_metric = 0
                epoch_metric_test = 0
                test_step = 0

                for test_data in test_loader:

                    test_step += 1

                    test_volume = test_data["vol"]
                    test_label = test_data["seg"]
                    test_label = test_label != 0
                    test_volume, test_label = (test_volume.to(device), test_label.to(device),)
                    
                    test_outputs = model(test_volume)
                    
                    test_loss = loss(test_outputs, test_label)
                    test_epoch_loss += test_loss.item()
                    test_metric = dice_metric(test_outputs, test_label)
                    epoch_metric_test += test_metric
                    
                
                test_epoch_loss /= test_step
                print(f'test_loss_epoch: {test_epoch_loss:.4f}')
                save_loss_test.append(test_epoch_loss)
                np.save(os.path.join(model_dir, 'loss_test.npy'), save_loss_test)

                epoch_metric_test /= test_step
                print(f'test_dice_epoch: {epoch_metric_test:.4f}')
                save_metric_test.append(epoch_metric_test)
                np.save(os.path.join(model_dir, 'metric_test.npy'), save_metric_test)

                if epoch_metric_test > best_metric:
                    best_metric = epoch_metric_test
                    best_metric_epoch = epoch + 1
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(
                        model_dir, "best_metric_model.pth"))
                
                print(
                    f"current epoch: {epoch + 1} current mean dice: {test_metric:.4f}"
                    f"\nbest mean dice: {best_metric:.4f} "
                    f"at epoch: {best_metric_epoch}"
                )


    print(
        f"train completed, best_metric: {best_metric:.4f} "
        f"at epoch: {best_metric_epoch}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your train_loader is empty.

The only way `train_step` can be zero is if you never enter the for loop: `for batch_data in train_loader:` which means train_loader is empty. Make sure that you set your dataset up correctly